# Splunk - How to extract two fileds distinct count one field by the other field?

Tags: regex, splunk, splunk-query

I have such events:

```
Id":"123456","string","groupId":"AB123"}]
```

I want to extract the fields `Id`, i.e. 123456 and `groupId`, i.e. `AB123`.

I tried this:

```
query 
| rex field=_raw "Id\":\"(?<Id>\d+)\".+groupId\W+(?<groupId>\w+)"
| timechart partial=f span=10m dc(Id) by groupId
```

It did not count anything.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Are you consuming everything? Try `(?s)Id\"\s*:\s*\"(?<Id>\d+)\".*?\"groupId\W+(?<groupId>\w+)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're grouping by a field that may not exist (did you mean `groupId` instead of `serviceId`?)

Second, are you *sure* your regular expression is correct?

This [tested](https://regex101.com/r/5jAkcf/1) one is simpler:

```
| rex field=_raw "Id\W+(?<Id>\d+)\D+groupId\W+(?<groupid>\w+)"
```